# Is there a way to configure shibboleth on tomcat without having to use httpd apache?

Tags: tomcat, httpd, shibboleth

I have working setup of shibboleth configured via httpd apache and then pass it on to  tomcat. Now is it possible to get rid of httpd portion alone and have tomcat handle shibboleth authentication by way of using the shibboleth daemon.

Comment: Are you talking about a shibboleth service provider, or an identity provider?

Comment: I am talking about shibboleth service provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the shibboleth SP code is only written in C++ at the moment, with the apache module, an IIS module and NSAPI module acting as an interface to the shibd. Any way you look at it seems like you would need to implement a fair chunk of the existing code in java as I could find no existing libraries that do this job specifically. There is an [opensaml-java](http://shibboleth.net/products/opensaml-java.html) library, but it's a little lower level than providing a java-based shibboleth SP.

Comment: Since this answer is quite old, I double checked this (2017), and it still holds true, as explained here in the Shibboleth documentation: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPJavaInstall